# Printing issue with IE due to CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing

I'm having an issue where a CSS trick I am using to make the sure the border-right of a column is the same vertical height of the largest vertical height of a column in a row through:

```css
.some-column {
  margin-bottom: -999px;
  padding-bottom: 999px;
  border-right: solid;
  }
```

The issue arises when I actually print in IE11. It will print the entirety of maximum height of border. The print preview shows the expected results, but when I actually print is when this issue happens. Chrome works fine, and prints properly.

Comment: Where did this trick come from? I've never heard of it.

Comment: I read it in an answer some time ago, it does work, everything works except for printing in IE.